# Perl Number::Bytes::Human

Tags: perl

I'm using this code to convert bytes into more readable format, e.g. 155K, 1.5M, 1.5G, but can't figure out from the explanation on CPAN how the converted values to be printed to the second digit after the decimal point and to be rounded.
Thanks.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Number::Bytes::Human qw(format_bytes);

my $bytes = format_bytes(-s $file);
```

Comment: This particular module is alpha, which might be worth taking into consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to control the number of decimals using [Number::Format](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number%3a%3aFormat):

```
use Number::Format qw(format_bytes);
print format_bytes(-s $file, precision => 2);
```

[Number::Bytes::Human](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number%3a%3aBytes%3a%3aHuman) does have a `round` option, but I do not see an option to set the precision.

Comment: use Number::Format is actually more suitable for my needs. Very helpful. Many thanks.